# PHP preg_replace an exact string with another

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a URL string for images in my system for both light and dark images.

LIGHT IMAGES: `http://www.example.org/logos/l/1.jpg`

DARK IMAGES:  `http://www.example.org/logos/d/1.jpg`

What I want to do is a `preg_replace` JUST on the `/l/` directory and replace for `/d/` to display the dark logo in places where there is a white background.

I have this currently:

`<?php $img = preg_replace("/l/", "/d/", $image); ?>`

But this replaces all instances of the `l` character so you end up with: `http://www.exampde.org/dogos/d/1.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` are acting as delimiters in your regex pattern.  Use something else as the delimiter and keep the `/` as part of the required match:

```
$img = preg_replace("#/l/#", "/d/", $image);
```

It would be simpler and faster to not use regex:

```
$img = str_replace("/l/", "/d/", $image);
```